# Relation between variation of lagrangian and vacuum expectation value

Tags: quantum-field-theory, variational-principle, action

Recently, I am struggling to review some fundamental things in quantum field theories.

If $\delta L=0$, then the expectation value of variation of operator vanishes, *i.e*, $\langle  T(\delta O)\rangle=0$ where $\langle\,\cdot\,\rangle$ means vacuum expectation value, and $T$ stands for time ordering.

How this be true? How can prove this? any ideas or references?

I am trying to find some reference, if you know any please let me know. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is essentially due to [Schwinger's quantum action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger's_quantum_action_principle), 
$$
\delta \langle A|B\rangle=i\langle A|\delta S|B\rangle
$$

If $\delta L=0$ then $\delta S=0$, and so
$$
\delta \langle A|B\rangle=0
$$

Now take for example $\langle A|=\langle 0|$ and $|B\rangle=O|0\rangle$ so that
$$
0=\delta \langle 0|O|0\rangle=\langle 0|\delta O|0\rangle
$$

The modern interpretation of Schwinger's principle is through functional-integrals. I leave it to you to repeat the analysis above using them. The starting point is of course
$$
\langle O \rangle=\int\mathrm d\phi\ O(\phi)\,\mathrm e^{iS[\phi]}
$$
so that
$$
\langle \delta O \rangle=\int\mathrm d\phi\ O(\phi)\,\delta S[\phi]\, \mathrm e^{iS[\phi]}
$$
from which your result readily follows.